Flexbox Scrolling Issue
I have a page with an h1 and a p on top, and a div on the bottom.
The div have 2 divs inside, but it isn't allowing me to see the whole thing on mobile. As in it isn't allowing me to scroll.
I do NOT want overflow-y because I want the entire page to scroll if the content is too large.
I tried adding overflow-y, but that didn't do as I expected.


#shapes {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-y: visible;
}
<div id='noPw-email'>
  <div id='nopw-sucess'>
    <div class='tb-sucess' id='tb-sucesstop'>
      <p>Sucess!</p>
    </div>
    <img id='sucess-check' src='https://cdn.prestonkwei.com/circlewithcheck.png'>
    <div class='tb-sucess' id='tb-sucessbottom'>
      <p>You may now close this tab.
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Select the Matching Shape</h1>
  <p>Check your device, and click the matching shape to finish logging in!</p>
  <div id='shapes'>
    <div id='shape1' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='' class='emailshape' id='shape1-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape1-label'></p>
    </div>
    <div id='shape2' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='' class='emailshape' id='shape2-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape2-label'></p>
    </div>
    <div id='shape3' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='' class='emailshape' id='shape3-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape3-label'></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




I'm unsure what you want, maybe include a quick sketch in your question

This code will help you to see your result on mobile also and according to length of your content it will scroll. And also this code not include overflow-y:scroll;.


#shapes {
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.emailshape {
    width: 40px;
    background: #000;
}
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#sucess-check, .emailshape {
    background: #000;
    width: 40px;
}
<div id='noPw-email'>
  <div id='nopw-sucess'>
    <div class='tb-sucess' id='tb-sucesstop'>
      <p>Sucess!</p>
    </div>
    <img id='sucess-check' src='https://cdn.prestonkwei.com/circlewithcheck.png'>
    <div class='tb-sucess' id='tb-sucessbottom'>
      <p>You may now close this tab.
        <p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1>Select the Matching Shape</h1>
  <p>Check your device, and click the matching shape to finish logging in!</p>
  <div id='shapes'>
    <div id='shape1' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='https://cdn.prestonkwei.com/circlewithcheck.png' class='emailshape' id='shape1-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape1-label'>One</p>
    </div>
    <div id='shape2' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='https://cdn.prestonkwei.com/circlewithcheck.png' class='emailshape' id='shape2-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape2-label'>Two</p>
    </div>
    <div id='shape3' class='email-shapeselect'>
      <img src='https://cdn.prestonkwei.com/circlewithcheck.png' class='emailshape' id='shape3-img'>
      <p class='pk-nm-tb' id='shape3-label'>Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



